# Add covariance to gazebo sensors in ROS2 Gazebo Garden

Tags: gazebo, ros2, simulation, gps, sensor

Currently my ROS2 simulation doesn't populate non-zero a covariance for `/imu/data` or `/gps/fix`. I would like to have covariance in the output. How can I add covariance to the gz sensor output?

I have found some ways which tell me that I either have to write a node to manually populate the fields OR i have to write a plugin (I am not sure how to do that, couldn't find plugin documentation in Gazebo garden). Let me know if you know about this! Thanks!